# How to stop logstash input when an output error occurs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, apache-kafka

I'm running a logstash instance that reads some records from kafka and inserts them onto elasticsearch.
I had a problem with the elasticsearch configuration and new records weren't being inserted into elasticsearch.

Eventually I was able to fix the elasticsearch output. But even though the elasticsearch output wasn't able to write the records logstash didn't stop reading in more data from kafka.
So when I restarted logstash, it didn't pick up from the last successful kafka offset. Basically I lost all the records since the elasticsearch output stopped writing records.

How can I avoid that from happening again? Is there a way to stop the whole pipeline when there is an error on the output?

My simplified config file:

```
input {
    kafka {
            zk_connect => "zk01:2181,zk02:2181,zk03:2181/kafka"
            topic_id => "my-topic"
            auto_offset_reset => "smallest"
            group_id => "logstash-es"
            codec => "json"
    }
}
output {
            elasticsearch {
                    index => "index-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
                    document_type => "dev"
                    hosts => ["elasticsearch01","elasticsearch02","elasticsearch03","elasticsearch04","elasticsearch05","elasticsearch06"]
                    template => "/my-template.json"
                    template_overwrite => true
                    manage_template => true
            }
}
```

Comment: Please Add your codes to question !

Comment: Since you're using Kafka, you're not losing any records, but you can replay them from anywhere at any time, that's the big plus with Kafka (among others). You can manage the current offset for the "logstash-es" consumer group by using the Offset Management API and go back to the record that first failed.

Comment: Yes, I'm not losing any records. What I'm losing is the offset of when I've stopped writing to elasticsearch. So in order to find that offset I would have to look in the logs for the exact record that failed, somehow find the offset for that record and then change the offset in kafka for my consumer group. 
It might be possible to do but that would be a painful manual recovery mechanism. If there was a way for logstash to stop when a failure happens then it would be much easier. I could just fix the problem and restart logstash and it would pick up from where it left off.

Comment: Well, since there's no feedback loop from what the `elasticsearch` output does, your pipeline has basically no way of knowing when it starts failing. As far as I know, that is.

Comment: I do find that a bit odd. Is my use case that uncommon? Or maybe logstash is not the right tool for my use case.

Comment: same issue here